Counting f-invariant subspaces over finite fields
Riffing off of On the number of $f$-stable subsets which I very much enjoyed thinking about, let $f : V \to V$ be a linear map on an $n$-dimensional vector space over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ and define $I(f) = \{ W \subseteq V : f(W) \subseteq W \}$ to be the number of $f$-invariant subspaces of $W$.

What can we say about the number $I(f)$?

In addition to considering the question for a fixed value of $f$, it's also interesting to consider two ways $f$ can vary in families: first, given $f$ defined over $\mathbb{F}_q$ we can extend scalars to define $f/\mathbb{F}_{q^k}$ over $\mathbb{F}_{q^k}$, and consider the family of counts $I(f/\mathbb{F}_{q^k})$. Second, given $f$ defined over $\mathbb{Z}$ (so acting on a finite free $\mathbb{Z}$-module) we can extend scalars to define $f/\mathbb{F}_q$ over any finite field, and consider the family of counts $I(f/\mathbb{F}_q)$. I think taking $f$-invariant subspaces defines a scheme, specifically a projective subscheme of the disjoint union of the Grassmannians $\text{Gr}_k(V)$; if so these point counts are related to the cohomology of this scheme by the Weil conjectures.
Anyway, here's what I've got so far. The easiest special case is that $f$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{F}_q$ with distinct eigenvalues; in this case an $f$-invariant subspace is exactly a direct sum of some subset of the $1$-dimensional eigenspaces, which gives $I(f) = 2^n$. This is analogous to the case where $f$ is the identity in the set version of the problem.
If $f$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{F}_q$ but its eigenspaces have dimensions $m_{\lambda} = \dim V_{\lambda}$, then an $f$-invariant subspace is a direct sum of subspaces of the eigenspaces, which gives
$$I(f) = \prod_{\lambda} \left( \sum_{k=0}^{m_{\lambda}} {m_{\lambda} \choose k}_q \right)$$
where ${n \choose k}_q$ is the $q$-binomial coefficients, so the factor in the product corresponding to $\lambda$ counts the total number of subspaces of $V_{\lambda}$. This is analogous to the case where $f$ is invertible in the set version of the problem. In scheme terms, the scheme of $f$-invariant subspaces in this case is a product of disjoint unions of Grassmannians.
This calculation correctly suggests that we can reduce to considering one (generalized) eigenspace at a time. More precisely, if the characteristic polynomial of $f$ has irreducible factorization $\prod p_i(t)^{m_i}$ over $\mathbb{F}_q$, and we write $V$ as a direct sum of the generalized eigenspaces $V_i = \ker(p_i(f)^{m_i})$ and write $f_i : V_i \to V_i$ for the corresponding restrictions, then an $f$-invariant subspace of $V$ is exactly a tuple of $f_i$-invariant subspaces of each $V_i$, so
$$I(f) = \prod_i I(f_i).$$
(This follows e.g. from the Chinese remainder theorem applied to the $\mathbb{F}_q[t]/\prod p_i(t)^{m_i}$-module structure on $V$ where $t$ acts by $f$.) So we can reduce WLOG to the case that the characteristic polynomial of $f$ is primary (a power of an irreducible). This is analogous to the reduction to the case that $f$ has one connected component in the set case. However, unlike the set case, it is not true that $f$ is multiplicative under direct sums in general, which complicates things.
The case that the characteristic polynomial $p(t)$ is irreducible is not so bad; in this case $\mathbb{F}_q[t]/p(t) \cong \mathbb{F}_{q^n}$ is a field so $f$-invariant subspaces correspond to $\mathbb{F}_{q^n}$-subspaces of a $1$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}_{q^n}$, of which there are $2$. So $I(f) = 2$ in this case.
The next interesting case after this is the case that the characteristic polynomial has the form $(t - \lambda)^n$; since the $f$-invariant subspaces don't change if we replace $f$ with $f - \lambda$ we can assume WLOG that $\lambda = 0$, so we can reduce to the case that $f$ is nilpotent. If $f$ has a single Jordan block then $f$ preserves a complete flag of $V$ given by its generalized eigenspaces $\ker(f^k)$, and these are the only $f$-invariant subspaces, so $I(f) = n + 1$ in this case. However the case that $f$ has multiple Jordan blocks seems complicated, and I'm not sure how it works in general. Here Jordan chains are analogous to the "trees" in the set version of the problem. There appears to be a version of the third case of the "$I$-recursion" (see the original linked question) in this case but I'm not sure how complicated it ends up being.
The general case of characteristic polynomial $p(t)^m$ ought to be a mix of the previous two cases but I'm also not sure how it works in general. Also I have not thought much about what happens if $f$ varies in families as described above.
Also there is another variant of this question we could ask where we count subgroups of finite abelian groups (this amounts to replacing the polynomial ring $\mathbb{F}_q[t]$ by $\mathbb{Z}$), which surely must be known and very classical.
